# How to switch a getElementById to getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to switch a getElementById to getElementsByClassName

for a project like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/2waZ2/21/

My simple efforts just dont work:  http://jsfiddle.net/2waZ2/27/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
document.getElementsByClassName('mytable').appendChild( row ) ;
```

to

```
document.getElementsByClassName('mytable')[0].appendChild( row ) ;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2waZ2/30

and also remove dot in your class name.

Or easily use jQuery

```
row = displayArrayAsTable(QR4, 24, 25);
$(".mytable").append(row);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2waZ2/32/

Comment: Thats sweet - what dies the [0] mean?   I tried with and without the .class and I saw someone using it so I thought maybe...

Comment: @Jon edited. getElementsByClassName gives an array instead of selected element

Comment: @Jon dot is used in jquery and also in CSS

Comment: @Jon `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements (hence "elements"). To get the first item of an array, you use `[0]`.

Comment: an array of classes - brilliant.  That has allowed me to do some cool stuff.  Thanks for the help.  Great answer - dont know why my q was marked down!

Answer (score 0):

Almost there, you just need to remove the dot in getElementsByClassName and only get the first result from that, like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('mytable')[0]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2waZ2/33/

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns array of elements, not single element, as `getElementById`. So you should iterate over your collection (unless you want to append only to first found element) with:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('mytable');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { elements[i].appendChild( row ) };
```

Also remove dot from class name, as it's not part of class name (the same as # is not part of id)